# How to say "views" speaking about video sharing platforms?

Tags: technology

I find it very difficult to say the word "view" speaking about online video sharing platforms (Youtube, Bilibili, etc.).

The term for "to view (a video)" is 观看.
https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/11977233?hl=zh-Hans&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid

But I'm pretty sure we can't say 一个观看. **Edit**: Wrong. We can say "这个视频有几百万的观看"

There are the terms 播放量 (quantity of broadcasting?), or 浏览量 (website traffic), but there is not relationship between neither "view", nor the "unit" (1, 2, 3...). There is also the term 点阅率 (click-through rates), but at least according to my dictionary the term 点阅 alone doesn’t exist.

On Bibili, the number of views is not accompanied by any word (unlike on Youtube where it's written, e.g. "12,000 views"):
https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1WE411F7Mb/?spm_id_from=333.999.0.0

On Youku, the number of views is not indicated:
https://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XNDQ0ODU5NzUyMA==.html?spm=a2hja.14919748_WEBLIFE_JINGXUAN.drawer12.d_zj1_2&playMode=pugv&scm=20140719.manual.4714.video_XNDQ0ODU5NzUyMA%3D%3D&playMode=pugv

Same for iQIYI:
https://www.iqiyi.com/v_1arf1qlyonc.html?vfrm=pcw_category_lib_2&vfrmblk=E&vfrmrst=1_3

**Question:**

Concretely, how do we say: "Her video gained 3000 views in 2 hours", or "By viewing your video, she added you 1 more view!"

Comment: I wonder if [人次](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E4%BA%BA%E6%AC%A1/382605) works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can say

The "Dr.K vs. Little Pink" video has reached 9.4 million views

- 《Dr.K vs. 小粉红》视频有940萬個點擊
- 《Dr.K vs. 小粉红》视频有940萬個收視
- 《Dr.K vs. 小粉红》视频点击量已达940万次
- 《Dr.K vs. 小粉红》视频收視量已达940万次

Note:

940万個点击(click) or 收視(view) doesn't mean there are 9.4 million unique viewers, I watched it four or five times

收視(view) is not 收視率 (rating)

收視 = view

收視量 = the total number of views

点击(播放) = click (and play)

點擊(播放)量 = the total number of clicks (and play)

Comment: The video  has 9.4M views as I am typing this, I will edit my answer to reflect it

Comment: Sorry if you did not receive the comment. It was this one " Dear Tang Ho, for each example concerning Dr. K, can we replace "800萬" by "1"? (sorry if it's a stupid question... just would like to be sure)". So can we say 這個视频有1個點擊?

Comment: Yes, "只有一個點擊" or "點擊(播放)量只有一次" (can't say 已达 for obvious reason)

Answer (score 2):

liúlànliàng
浏览量

Her video gained 3000 views in 2 hours.
她的视频在两个小时内得了三千浏览量.

Comment: Can we say  她的视频在两个小时内得了一浏览量?

Comment: Maybe better like this: 她的视频在两个小时内只有一个人浏览过.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest minor modifications and adding a measure word to Pedroski's sentence:

- 她的视频在两个小时内"獲得"/"贏得"了三千**次**的浏览量.

And, with a slight twist, one can say:

- 她的视频在两个小时内**被**"浏览"/"(观)看"了三千次